# Get identity provider oauth tokens in AWS cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

Is there ANY possible way to get an identity providers oauth tokens when signing them up for a user pool? I need offline access to a google users access and refresh tokens. So far I've tried:

**1) Using the [amazon-cognito-auth-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js) library**

I'm able to create a user but there is no way to get the oauth access and refresh tokens. It looks like attribute mapping should achieve this, but in the mapping select box there is [no option for access/refresh tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28gOM.png).

**2) Login with google javascript api and create user via [cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property)**

This flow would be:

- Login via [gapi](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) and get the oauth `authorization_code`
- Send `authorization_code` to an HTTP lambda function to exchange for access and refresh tokens.
- Create a new userpool user with `adminCreateUser`
- Add the refresh / access tokens to this user.

Although, it appears as if there is no way to `adminCreateUser` with an identity provider. Only username / password.

**3) Login with gapi and make an ajax call to `oauth2/idpresponse`**

Similar to the last flow, I would:

- Login via [gapi](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) and get the oauth `authorization_code`
- Send `authorization_code` to an HTTP lambda function to exchange for access and refresh tokens.
- Make a GET request to `https:<domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=<authorization_code>` which appears to be the step in the [amazon-cognito-auth-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js) library that signs up a new user.
- Add the refresh / access tokens to this user.

The GET request to `oauth2/idpresponse` always fails though.  There are other required query parameters besides `authorization_code` which I don't know how to get (state?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's answer if someone would encounter same issue

CAUTION - Doing it incorrectly, you expose sensitive attributes to client.

You need to create 2 versions of attributes - `custom` and `dev:custom`, map oidc provider attributes to `custom` ones (looks like `dev:custom` aren't mappable), then in `TokenGeneration_HostedAuth` trigger you need to get these `custom` attributes, set `dev:custom` ones, then delete `custom`s.

Seems like a tweak, but I don't see another way of doing it and keeping tokens safe.

Solution for that is to create custom attributes in your user pool, then map these attributes for identity provider. Looks something like:

```
'custom:refresh_token': refresh_token
'custom:id_token': id_token
'custom:access_token': access_token
```

Cloudformation template for that:

user pool

```
....
Schema: [
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        DeveloperOnlyAttribute: true,
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'refresh_token',
        Required: false,
    },
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        DeveloperOnlyAttribute: true,
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'access_token',
        Required: false,
    },
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        DeveloperOnlyAttribute: true,
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'id_token',
        Required: false,
    },
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'refresh_token',
        Required: false,
    },
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'access_token',
        Required: false,
    },
    {
        AttributeDataType: 'String',
        Mutable: true,
        Name: 'id_token',
        Required: false,
    },
],
....
```

user pool identity provider

```
....
AttributeMapping: {
    'custom:refresh_token': 'refresh_token',
    'custom:access_token': 'access_token',
    'custom:id_token': 'id_token',
},
....
```